Initials on luggage
I want to put a Korean persons initials on their luggage vertically.  Should I place their Family name at the top then first and middle or use regular order....First, middle, last.  Thank you for helping.

Do you mean initials in latin text? I assume you're not referring to hangul.

Ask to luggage owners.
Generally, when we use latin text, we follow your rules - Think JYP. His name is Park JinYoung, but he called JYP for himself and his company. we don't use middle name. his family name is Park and given name is JinYoung.
But some kind of people wants asian style - Family first, given name order. In this case, write PJY.
I don't know their wants.
